# How Can I navigate to a particular page in backstack in WP7.1

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-7.1, back-button, back-stack

How Can I navigate to a particular page depending  upon pagename in navigation backstack in Wp7.1. I want to go back to say A page from C page on press of device back button, I dont know how many pages are inbetween.

Thanks,
kanaya

Answer (score 0):

Look at 'back chaining':
http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/10/09/Back-Chaining-in-WP7.aspx

> Because we are only able to programmatically back-navigate one page at
>   a time, a technique has been devised in the developer community called
>   back-chaining.  Back-chaining simply involves setting certain flags in
>   your pages so that, if anyone ever backs into the page, it will
>   continue to navigate backwards.  In this way, we can chain several
>   back navigations together until we arrive at the page we want to stop
>   at.